# How to show Foldleft and grayscale effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want the foldLeft and grayscale effect on mouseover to an image ,i find 
the code

```
<script src="Adipoli-master/jquery.adipoli.js"></script>
```

http://cube3x.com/adipoli-jquery-image-hover-plugin/

```
  $('#image1').adipoli({
                    'startEffect': 'grayscale',
                    'hoverEffect': 'fold'
                });
```

the code above is working but i want reserve the hover effect when mouse leave the image.

http://codecanyon.net/item/picanim-jquery-image-hover-effect-pulgin/full_screen_preview/2835834   this link has that effect but its not working in IE

Comment: u want image should be in its normal state after `mouseleave`

Comment: yes, but with the same reserve effect